# AddingSensorsToPR2 tutorial errors

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am going through the [urdf/Tutorials/AddingSensorsToPR2  tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/AddingSensorsToPR2). This tutorial basically shows how to add new links and attach sensors to a link in gazebo.
Although the new links and joints can be added and viewed properly:

[image: image description]

I can find the ROS topic for the added camera. Here is a part of my xacro file, slightly modified from the original file on the tutorial page.

```
 <gazebo reference="finger_tip_camera_link">
  <sensor:camera name="finger_tip_camera_sensor">
    <imageSize>640 480</imageSize>
    <imageFormat>BAYER_BGGR8</imageFormat>
    <hfov>90</hfov>
    <nearClip>0.01</nearClip>
    <farClip>100</farClip>
    <updateRate>25.0</updateRate>
    <controller:gazebo_ros_camera name="finger_tip_camera_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>25.0</updateRate>
      <imageTopicName>finger_tip_cam/image</imageTopicName>
      <cameraInfoTopicName>finger_tip_cam/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
      <frameName>finger_tip_camera_link</frameName>
      <interface:camera name="finger_tip_camera_iface" />
    </controller:gazebo_ros_camera>
  </sensor:camera>
  <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  <material>PR2/Blue</material>
  </gazebo>
```

I didn't see any error message, just couldn't find the ROS image topic, which should be `finger_tip_cam/image` in this case.

Any idea what goes wrong and where can I find the documentation on the syntax of gazebo_plugin. The [Ros Camera Plugin XML Reference and Example here](http://www.ros.org/doc/diamondback/api/gazebo_plugins/html/group__GazeboRosCamera.html) is fairly limited, not detailed enough for me to understand...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11094/addingsensorstopr2-tutorial-errors/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-09-03**:
thank you i'll do that

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-09-03**:
Post the entire solution as an answer and then one of the site admins can come along and mark it as the actual accepted answer (currently, I don't think you can accept your own answer to your own question).

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-09-03**:
sorry for that, what should I do to close off this question?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-02**:
It sounds like you've already answered your own question.  Please close off this question if that is the case and don't incrementally ask new questions (use new posts to ask different questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I start up the gazebo world with pr2, there is some warnings:

```
[ WARN] [1314971961.560814557, 0.001000000]: urdf2gazebo: link(r_gripper_tool_frame) has no inertia, 1 children link ignored.
[ WARN] [1314971961.560901210, 0.001000000]: urdf2gazebo: link(r_gripper_tool_frame) has no inertia, 1 children joint ignored.
[ WARN] [1314971961.560934768, 0.001000000]: urdf2gazebo: link(r_gripper_tool_frame) has no inertia, parent joint(r_gripper_tool_joint) is ignored.
[ WARN] [1314971961.560967559, 0.001000000]: urdf2gazebo: link(r_gripper_tool_frame) has no inertia, not modeled in gazebo.
```

I added the intertia property to r_gripper_tool_frame which was originally defined in file "pr2_description/urdf/gripper.urdf.xacro" and it worked.

But i'm still wondering if there is detailed gazebo plugin XML reference.

---

Originally posted by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) with karma: 311 on 2011-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1